# Beginner Django / Python / Postgres dev struggling with no model data output to html file

Tags: django, postgresql

I have been working through some basic online Youtube tutorials for Django, which have been great, but I've been struggling the last few days with my Test-table app, being unable to display table data on my example Postgresql table placed on my index.html file. When I created the Postgres model (local hosted), it appears correctly with data in the admin page, and my index page loads successfully from my url and view file configurations, but is missing the table data specifically and I'm hoping for some guidance on what I am doing incorrectly. I understand there are more dynamic configurations for the URL and views, but I was attempting to get a basic one working first...

```
models.py file:

from django.db import models

class products(models.Model):
Phone = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
Version = models.TextField(max_length=100)
Price = models.FloatField()
Sales = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "productlist"

Url file:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'Test_table'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.sales),
]

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from Test_table.models import products
# from django.http import HttpResponse

def sales(request):

ph_data = products.objects.all(),
return render(request, 'Test_table/index.html', {'ph_data': ph_data})
```

html file:

```
<table border='3'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Version</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Sales</th>
                </tr>
                {% for i in ph_data %}
                <tr>
                    <td><h3>{{i.Phone}}</h3></td>
                    <td><h3>{{i.Version}}</h3></td>
                    <td><h3>{{i.Price}}</h3></td>
                    <td><h3>{{i.Sales}}</h3></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

Comment: you have comma in your view after  .all()

Comment: Also your coding style is off https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove **,** from `ph_data = products.objects.all(),` , rest is fine

Correct code :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Test_table.models import products
# from django.http import HttpResponse

def sales(request):
      ph_data = products.objects.all()
      return render(request, 'Test_table/index.html', {'ph_data': ph_data})
```

And make sure to add data from admin to products table to view it.